# rails: creating models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I have a model that looks like this:

```
The id of class and teacher is 1 to 1.
Class has_many grades
Grade belongs_to class
```

This is my home page controller:

```
  @grade = Grade.new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @grade }
  end
```

This is my grade controller:

```
  def create
    class = Class.find(current_teacher.id)
    ****@grade = class.grades.build(params[:grade])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @grade.save
        format.html { redirect_to @grade, notice: 'Grade was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @grade, status: :created, location: @grade }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @grade.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Currently I am getting this error on the line that has ****

```
unknown attribute: class_id
```

How to fix it?

Another question is I also have

```
grade belongs_to student
student belongs_to grade
```

How do I add this to the create/new method as well?

Comment: This is not going to work because `class` is a reserved word in Ruby. `Class` (with a capital) may work, but you'd better rename to `school_class` and `SchoolClass` or something.

Comment: The above being said, does your grades table have a column `class_id`? The error message suggests you don't.

Comment: I think so, the class show/edit/create/new page is working correctly.

Comment: but I am not sure, how do I ensure that I have it?

Comment: Assuming you are using sqlite, in your console type: `bundle exec rails db` and then `.schema`. This will show you the schema of your tables.

Comment: ok thx solved...I am trying to do my second question now.